# Django DB connection error when connecting to MariaDB: SSL connection error: The message received was unexpected or badly formatted

Tags: django, ssl, openssl, mariadb

I am trying to set up Django, but whenever Django tries to connect to my remote Database (MariaDB) with these Django settings:

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'xx',
        'HOST': 'xx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xx',
        'NAME': 'xx',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {'ssl': True},
    }
}
```

I get this error:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: The message received was unexpected or badly formatted')

The status of my MariaDB is

```
MariaDB [(none)]> status
--------------
C:\Program Files\MariaDB 11.2\bin\mysql.exe from 11.2.2-MariaDB, client 15.2 for Win64 (AMD64), source revision 929532a9426d085111c24c63de9c23cc54382259

Connection id:          98
Current database:
Current user:           mads@85.81.43.174
SSL:                    Cipher in use is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server:                 MariaDB
Server version:         10.5.22-MariaDB MariaDB Server
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             eccentric.dk via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8mb4
Conn.  characterset:    utf8mb4
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 2 hours 24 min 5 sec
```

and the SSL settings for the database:

```
MariaDB [(none)]>  SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%';
+---------------------+----------------------------------+
| Variable_name       | Value                            |
+---------------------+----------------------------------+
| have_openssl        | YES                              |
| have_ssl            | YES                              |
| ssl_ca              | /etc/mariadb/chain.pem           |
| ssl_capath          |                                  |
| ssl_cert            | /etc/mariadb/fullchain.pem       |
| ssl_cipher          |                                  |
| ssl_crl             |                                  |
| ssl_crlpath         |                                  |
| ssl_key             | /etc/mariadb/privkey.pem         |
| version_ssl_library | OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021 |
+---------------------+----------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.036 sec)
```

And TLS:

```
MariaDB [(none)]>  SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%tls%';
+---------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                   |
+---------------+-------------------------+
| tls_version   | TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3 |
+---------------+-------------------------+
```

I have these packages installed in my VEnv:

```
Package                Version
---------------------- -------
asgiref                3.7.2
Cython                 3.0.6
Django                 5.0
mariadb                1.1.8
mysql-connector-python 8.2.0
mysqlclient            2.2.0
packaging              23.2
pip                    23.3.1
protobuf               4.21.12
sqlparse               0.4.4
tzdata                 2023.3
wheel                  0.42.0
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are connecting with SSL True, you need to provide the key too.

sample code

```
'OPTIONS': {'ssl': {'key': '/map/to/ca-cert.pem'}}
```

The key should be provided by DBA as the key is configured in database.
for SSL configuration in maria DB check this link [maria db ssl](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/securing-connections-for-client-and-server/)

Comment: Which key? MariaDB uses a Let's Encrypt certificate

Comment: 1) You only need to provide a key if user was created with REQUIRE X509, Issuer or Certificate. 2. ca-cert contains  trusted certificate authorities but not a key